# Print out message with frame around it

Tags: java

The user types in message and whatever the want in the same sentence.

```
command > message A long message where there cant be more than 56 characters.
```

I want to take whatever the user types in after "message " and surround it with a box as such:

```
############################################################
#                                                          #
# A LONG MESSAGE WHERE THERE CANT BE MORE THAN 56 CHARACTE #
#                                                          #
############################################################
```

The frame should have a width of 60 spaces and atleast a blank space before and after the message. The message can't have a length more than 56 characters.

Here's what I tried but I keep getting the error: StringIndexOutOfBoundsException..

```
private void printBoxedMessage() {
    String shorterString = nextObjective.substring(8).toUpperCase();
    if (!(shorterString.equals(null))) {
        for (int n = 0; n < 5; n++) {
            if (n == 0 || n == 4) {
                for (int m = 0; m < 60; m++) {
                    System.out.print("#");
                }
            } else if (n == 1 || n == 3) {
                for (int y = 0; y < 60; y++) {
                    if (y == 0 || y == 59) {
                        System.out.print("#");
                    } else if (y > 0 && y < 60) {
                        System.out.print(" ");
                    }
                }
            } else if (n == 2) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
                    if (i == 0 || i == 59) {
                        System.out.print("#");
                    } else if (i == 1 || i == 58) {
                        System.out.print(" ");
                    } else if (i == 2) {
                        System.out.printf("%56s", shorterString.substring(0, 56));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I would handle this is by first checking if the String entered is more than 56 characters. If you don't want it to be, then make the user reenter. Other wise if you want the surrounding areas frame to match the length of what is entered then just create a for loop to match the length of the message entered.

```
public class PrintBoxedMethod {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Boolean lengthCheck = false;

    System.out.println("Enter a message up to 56 characters");
    String message = input.nextLine();

    while(lengthCheck == false){
    if(message.length()> 56){
        System.out.println("Message is too long, Enter a message up to 56 characters");
        message = input.nextLine();
    } else lengthCheck = true;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<message.length() + 4;i++){
        System.out.print("#");
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("# ");
    System.out.print(message);
    System.out.println(" #");
    for(int i = 0; i<message.length() + 4;i++){
        System.out.print("#");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Don't assume the String length.
(Correcting formatting)
Create an int for size using Math.min(), Then when you get a substring, use the size instead of the 56. For example on your first and last line, what happens if you have a string (nextObjective) shorter than 56 or 8?

```
  int size = Math.min(incomingString.length,56);
     ...
  System.out.printf("%56s", shorterString.substring(0, Math.min(size,56)));
```

Comment: Have a look at how to answer on stackoverflow . Edit your answer and do some formatting like 4 spaces at start of sentences makes that sentence a code piece. Welcome to stackoverflow :) @Dakoda

Answer (score 0):

Your code is really hard to understand (at least to me) without any comments to explain stuff. Let's try a more straightforward approach:

```
public static void boxMessage(String message) {
    // first line
    int length = message.length();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 60 ; i++) {
        System.out.print("#");
    }
    // second line
    System.out.print("\n#");
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 58 ; i++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.print("#\n");
    // third line. Left spaces is the number of spaces on the left of the message.
    System.out.print("# ");
    int leftSpaces = (58 - message.length()) / 2;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < leftSpaces ; i++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.print(message);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 58 - leftSpaces - length ; i++) { // 58 - leftSpaces - length is number of spaces the right side should have.
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

    System.out.print(" #\n");
    // fourth line
    System.out.print("#")
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 58 ; i++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.print("#\n");
    // last line
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 60 ; i++) {
        System.out.print("#");
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
boxMessage("A LONG MESSAGE WHERE THERE CANT BE MORE THAN 56 CHARACTE");
```

prints:

```
############################################################
#                                                          #
# A LONG MESSAGE WHERE THERE CANT BE MORE THAN 56 CHARACTE #
#                                                          #
############################################################
```

Comment: @Fresh Java oh I misunderstood your question, I will edit it

Comment: @FreshJava Edited, is that what you want?

Comment: @FreshJava you should check whether message is longer than 56 chars

Comment: @FreshJava it should be fixed now

Comment: crap, now if the message isn't 56 chars long, lets say its 5 and says "hello", the message will be centered but the # will be to the right of the right. Not in line with the others in other words :S